# qemu-aarch64: Could not open '/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1': No such file or directory

Tags: qemu, arm64

I'm sure this is a dumb question, but I'm new to QEMU so please bear with me.

```
└──╼ $ qemu-aarch64 ./a.out
qemu-aarch64: Could not open '/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1': No such file or directory
```

I'm *assuming* I just failed to install something, but I can't seem to figure it out and SO would probably shoot this question down so here I am.

Thanks in advance.

OS: Linux ParrotOS
Arch: x86-64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the relevant C library. Since Parrot OS is based on Debian, and provides `arm64` binaries, the following should work:

- Enable the `arm64` architecture (this matches `aarch64`):

  ```
  sudo dpkg --add-architecture arm64
  ```
- Update the local repository caches:

  ```
  sudo apt update
  ```
- Install the `arm64` C library:

  ```
  sudo apt install libc6:arm64
  ```

This will fail if your system isn’t up-to-date, so you may need to run `sudo apt upgrade` first. If `a.out` needs other libraries, you’ll need to install the corresponding `:arm64` packages too.